# Why does Charles zi Britannia say "Yes, you're worthy of being called my child now!" at Lelouch's action?

Tags: code-geass

I've only seen the English dub of *Code Geass* and this scene is from it.

We learn later on that in the end, Charles was not evil and he was trying to create a better world just like Lelouch. So, when Lelouch did something truly evil in the anime at some point (I think it was when that ship full of material exploded and took their allies out with it), he said

> Yes, you're worthy of being called my child now!

Why does Charles say that since he's not truly evil?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exploding ship was episode 13, but the Charles scene you're referring to is episode 22 with Euphy.
Charles didn't actually say that, it's a mistranslation. Charles said "he did it, he really did it", and what Charles most likely was talking about was Lelouch developing his geass to a higher level, and not the consequences of that development.